# Vuetify checkbox in v-for only works if label clicked

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

Hi have the following statement.

```
<li
                v-for="(area, i) in areas"
                :key="i"
                style="display: flex; justify-content: space-evenly; flex-wrap: wrap;"
              >
                <v-checkbox
                  @click="areaClick"
                  v-model="area.areaChosen"
                  :id="area.id.toString()"
                  :label="area.area_description"
                  color="beige lighten-1"
                ></v-checkbox>
              </li>
```

It displays as follows: [image: checkbox ul]

My problem is that if you click on the checkbox itself (The square) then nothing happens however if you click on the label eg, Atlantic Seaboard then it works correctly.

I would like it to work when I click on the square as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats why you're using `@click` handler. According to [docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/pt-BR/components/selection-controls), try `@change`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `@click.capture` this will still allow you to click on both the checkmark and label.

```
<v-checkbox
  @click.capture="areaClick"
  v-model="area.areaChosen"
></v-checkbox>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem could also be with your version of Vue/Vuetify. When I updated the libraries (Vue.js from 2.6.10 to 2.6.14 and Vuetify from 2.0.17 to 2.6.6), it started working.